# Node RESTful API to Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, stripe-payments, google-cloud-functions

I got a working app in Node.js, that's gonna take care of [Stripe](https://stripe.com/no)charges. As I'm hosting with [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/), I need to use the Google [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions) in order to take care of this. Is there an easy way to 'translate' my code, to a cloud function in `index.js`?

`exports.stripecharge = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) =>`
Not sure how to implement this to my existing code

This is my working API (testkeys modified):

```
var stripe = require("stripe")("sk_test_213123123123123");
var express = require('express'), bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })
var app = express();


app.get('/',function(req, res) {
 // for kicks, just sending checkout
 res.send('<form action="/charge" method="POST">Buy it !<script 
src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button" data-
key="pk_test_123123123123213"></script></form>')
});


app.post('/charge',urlencodedParser, function(req, res) {

// grab a token
var token = req.body.stripeToken;

// creating a charge, for real use add things like error handling
stripe.charges.create({
amount: 2000,
currency: "usd",
source: token, // obtained with Stripe.js
description: "Charge"
}, function(err, charge) {
  res.send("You made a charge: "+ charge.id);
 });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you already have a working Express app.  It turns out that you can pass an Express app to Cloud Functions:

```
exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app)
```

When you do this, all the routes from your app will be handled by Cloud Functions.  The path of the URLs will be prefixed by the name of the function.  In the above case, that's "api", so the paths will be `/api/` and `/api/charge`, etc.

You can see [one example](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/authenticated-json-api) of this in the [Firebase samples repo](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/).

Comment: Okay, that's neat. Can I use this code in the existing Express app `server.js` with `const functions = require('firebase-functions');`, and deploy it to my Firebase-project some way, or am I supposed to copy over my code to the `Index.js`, and require Express in the `Index.js`?

Comment: It doesn't matter how you organize your code, but your index.js module has to export the HTTPS function so that Cloud Functions will pick it up.

Comment: Okay thanks. What I meant was: Is it possible to refer in the `Index.js`, to the external `server.js`(The Express app), and deploy it this way? So they stay as separate files on my system. If so, how is this done?

Comment: Probably not without making some changes.  You might want to read up on how modules work with node.  There's nothing unique about the way `require` works in Cloud Functions.

Comment: Yeah, I'll dig into that. Regarding the URL paths: In my HTML post form, I should set the `action` to `/functionname/charge` for it to work? Sry for asking so much

Comment: Cloud Functions are served from a different host than your web site, so you would also have to use CORS, or integrate with Firebase Hosting.